# How to find idea for essay

Tags: molecular-biology, molecular-genetics, research-process, research-tools, research-design

I'm studying microbiology in Iran
The university that I'm studying in doesn't provide that much help in research areas and we don't get to research or write essays that much ,while I'm trying to write an ISI essay and communicate with universities abroad in order to get admission for my masters degree and be able to study abroad
But the problem is , I don't know how to start and find ideas for writing papers and research
Like, what is the first step you take as a scientist when you want to start research?

Comment: This question would be better suited to the academia stack exchange.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to start by browsing the research papers (think of them as "essays") at https://www.plos.org/ to find the areas you are most interested in.  They have thousands of peer-reviewed articles which you can read for ideas for your essay and research ideas.   You might then consider contacting the authors of those papers to inquire about education or work at their institutions.